# Nested For Loop in Shell Script not correctly iterating over arrays

Tags: arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to use nested for loops to create files. I have three arrays as follows:

```
    a=( 1000 2000 3000 )
    b=( 10515 7515 4515 )
    c=( 10 20 30 40 )
```

Using these arrays will specify what files my for loop will search through (for the purpose of copying data from pre-existing files and copying them into newly created files).

```
    for tom in "${tom[@]}"
    do
       for dick in "${dick[@]}"
       do
          for harry in "${harry[@]}"
          do
             FILENAME="this_is_file_${tom}_${dick}_c0.out"
             NEWFILE="this_is_newfile_${tom}_${dick}_${harry}.out"
             cat $FILENAME >> $NEWFILE
             awk 'NR==n{$3=a}1' n="${x}" a="${harry}" $NEWFILE &> tmp && mv tmp $NEWFILE
             mv $NEWFILE NewFiles
             done
          done
       done
    done
```

(I have already defined x="string"). So far my code generates all the files HOWEVER when the for loop goes through one iteration, the next loop back into  starts at the last array value 4515 and skips the first 10515 value. I get 40 files which is the correct number, but when tom's array is on value 2000 and 3000, dick's array generates files using only array values 7515 and 4515. it repeats the value 4515 twice giving the following list of files:

```
this_is_newfile_1000_10515_10.out
this_is_newfile_1000_10515_20.out
this_is_newfile_1000_10515_30.out
this_is_newfile_1000_10515_40.out
this_is_newfile_1000_7515_10.out
this_is_newfile_1000_7515_20.out
this_is_newfile_1000_7515_30.out
this_is_newfile_1000_7515_40.out
this_is_newfile_1000_4515_10.out
this_is_newfile_1000_4515_20.out
this_is_newfile_1000_4515_30.out
this_is_newfile_1000_4515_40.out
```

Here is where it gets funky, notice for tom's array value 2000, dick's value remains 4515 instead of looping back to 10515.

```
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_10.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_20.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_30.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_40.out
this_is_newfile_2000_7515_10.out
this_is_newfile_2000_7515_20.out
this_is_newfile_2000_7515_30.out
this_is_newfile_2000_7515_40.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_10.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_20.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_30.out
this_is_newfile_2000_4515_40.out
```

(Sorry for long list I wanted to make it clear what was happening) This repeats for toms array value of 3000. Can anyone help with this? I have another question in regards to the line using awk that I will post in another entry.

Comment: There is a brace missing in `"$b[@]}"`, no dollar in `"c{[@]}"`, one `done` too many - you actually got this running?

Comment: That was a typo when I was typing it here. Those weren't my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue. In the For loop, I use tom, dick and harry as variables. However in defining them the arrays are

```
tom=(values)
dick=(values)
harry=(values)
```

The variable name was the same as the "counter" variable in the for loop.

```
for tom in ${tom[@]}
do
   something
done
```

It instead should be something like this:

```
for i in ${tom[@]}
```

where the i or some other variable different from tom should be used. This fixed the problem.